# ibatis dynamic select statement with two dynamic prepend="WHERE"

Tags: sql-server, ibatis

Hello I would like to do a A complex dynamic select statement with two dynamic prepend="WHERE"

I wrote this in file xml:

```
<select id="myQuery" parameterClass="myClass" resultClass="myResultClass">
SELECT sum(numRows), Sum(fatturato)  FROM
(
    SELECT count(*) as numRighe, ISNULL(sum(a.fatture),0) as fatturato
    FROM MyTable
  <dynamic prepend="WHERE">
   <isNotNull prepend="AND" property="field">
   (code= #field#)
   </isNotNull>
 </dynamic>
  union ALL
  SELECT count(*) as numRighe, ISNULL(sum(a.fatture),0) as fatturato
  FROM TABLE_2
  <dynamic prepend="WHERE">
  <isNotNull prepend="AND" property="field">
  (code= #field#)
  </isNotNull>
  </dynamic>
) as Query
</select>
```

If I execute query on Sql Server it return successfully results
ma with Ibatis, launching a method java , debugging result is  0.

Is it possibile to do the statement in IBATIS to build dinamically the where of the two subqueries?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do like this in your case:

```
   WHERE 1=1 AND 
   <isNotNull prepend="AND" property="field">
      (code= #field#)
   </isNotNull>
```

But this should not affect the result.

I suspect that the data type of "code" field is Varchar2. If so, check whether the #field# parameter was trimmed or not. There's maybe some superfluous spaces in the parameter. Also check the "code" field in DB whether data containing superfluous space character. This can make you become miserable when trying to detecting problem.